# Is there a story for how striking and fielding games started in Spain?

Tags: spain, sports

I have done some research to find the origins of striking and fielding games in Spain and have found that Gilli-Danda and Basque Pelota are the oldest forms of striking and fielding games played in Spain. But now I'm wondering whether or not there is a story to how the game was formed. For example, the beginning of rugby was in a football game. While the players were playing normally, one person just picked up the ball and run to the end -- hence, rugby was born. Is there a story like this one for striking and fielding games?

Comment: Which Spain, exactly?